# Correct 'SameAs' Schema Coding

Tags: schema, schema.org, jsonschema

I have a client who operates two different blogs on different domains. One domain/blog is b2c focused, while the other is b2b focused. Having it on two domains allows them to specifically target each separate audience and not bombard their b2c crowd with information that's irrelevant to them.

What we would like to achieve is to have both blogs surface for branded related search terms. So I'm wondering if schema 'sameas' would be appropriate in communicating to Google that both domains are of the same ownership and property.

Secondly, the business is also known to the public by two different names. One being a short-hand form and the other being the full LLC name. Both of which are searched frequently. So what I have is as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "Short Hand",
    "alternateName" : "Full llc",
    "url" : "http://b2c.com",
    "sameAs" : [
    "http://b2b.com"
   ]
}
</script>
```

Just want to confirm that I understand this schema and I'm implementing it properly. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Do both sites contain information about the organization (like an "About" page, a "Contact" page etc.), or is one of the sites a blog only?

Comment: The 2nd site features contact information, but it's mainly a blog. Contact information is found in the footer and different CTA's.